# Move column by name to front of table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, move, dataframe, shift

Here is my df:

```
                             Net   Upper   Lower  Mid  Zsore
Answer option                                                
More than once a day          0%   0.22%  -0.12%   2    65 
Once a day                    0%   0.32%  -0.19%   3    45
Several times a week          2%   2.45%   1.10%   4    78
Once a week                   1%   1.63%  -0.40%   6    65
```

How can I move a column by name (`"Mid"`) to the front of the table, index 0. This is what the result should look like:

```
                             Mid   Upper   Lower  Net  Zsore
Answer option                                                
More than once a day          2   0.22%  -0.12%   0%    65 
Once a day                    3   0.32%  -0.19%   0%    45
Several times a week          4   2.45%   1.10%   2%    78
Once a week                   6   1.63%  -0.40%   1%    65
```

My current code moves the column by index using `df.columns.tolist()` but I'd like to shift it by name.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

We can use `loc` to reorder by passing a list:

```
In [27]:
# get a list of columns
cols = list(df)
# move the column to head of list using index, pop and insert
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('Mid')))
cols
Out[27]:
['Mid', 'Net', 'Upper', 'Lower', 'Zsore']
In [28]:
# use ix to reorder
df = df.loc[:, cols]
df
Out[28]:
                      Mid Net  Upper   Lower  Zsore
Answer_option                                      
More_than_once_a_day    2  0%  0.22%  -0.12%     65
Once_a_day              3  0%  0.32%  -0.19%     45
Several_times_a_week    4  2%  2.45%   1.10%     78
Once_a_week             6  1%  1.63%  -0.40%     65
```

Another method is to take a reference to the column and reinsert it at the front:

```
In [39]:
mid = df['Mid']
df.drop(labels=['Mid'], axis=1,inplace = True)
df.insert(0, 'Mid', mid)
df
Out[39]:
                      Mid Net  Upper   Lower  Zsore
Answer_option                                      
More_than_once_a_day    2  0%  0.22%  -0.12%     65
Once_a_day              3  0%  0.32%  -0.19%     45
Several_times_a_week    4  2%  2.45%   1.10%     78
Once_a_week             6  1%  1.63%  -0.40%     65
```

You can, with very early versions of Pandas, also use `ix` to achieve the same results:

```
df = df.ix[:, cols]
```

But `ix` was deprecated from pandas [`0.20.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix) onwards and was [discontinued as of Pandas 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/pandas-loc-vs-iloc-vs-at-vs-iat).

Comment: I also use .loc with a list to re-order columns. I frequently want to move a newly-created column (at the far right) to the front, (i.e. left), for which I use `df.loc[:, np.roll(df.columns, 1)]`. Not sure whether that's easier to read than the list comprehensions others have noted elsewhere on this page, but I use numpy a lot so I find it easy. Cheers!

Answer (score 142):

Maybe I'm missing something, but a lot of these answers seem overly complicated.  You should be able to just set the columns within a single list:

Column to the front:

```
df = df[ ['Mid'] + [ col for col in df.columns if col != 'Mid' ] ]
```

Or if instead, you want to move it to the back:

```
df = df[ [ col for col in df.columns if col != 'Mid' ] + ['Mid'] ]
```

Or if you wanted to move more than one column:

```
cols_to_move = ['Mid', 'Zsore']
df           = df[ cols_to_move + [ col for col in df.columns if col not in cols_to_move ] ]
```

Comment: For anyone else, make sure for multiple columns you use option 3. Option 1 with multiple columns won't delete `Mid` & `Zscore` from column from the original position. I found this out with a `Grouper` error trying to groupby when the same column was there twice.

Comment: @kevin_theinfinityfund I think that only would have happened if you did `if col != 'Mid' or col != 'Zscore'` -- with `if col != 'Mid' and col != 'Zscore'` it will not duplicate the columns. Or even better: `if col not in ('Mid', 'Zscore')`.

Comment: Yes the 3rd piece you offered is the 3rd option I referenced. It is the cleanest way to go about multiple columns.

Answer (score 126):

I prefer this solution:

```
col = df.pop("Mid")
df.insert(0, col.name, col)
```

It's simpler to read and faster than other suggested answers.

```
def move_column_inplace(df, col, pos):
    col = df.pop(col)
    df.insert(pos, col.name, col)
```

---

**Performance assessment:**

For this test, the currently last column is moved to the front in each repetition. In-place methods generally perform better. While citynorman's solution can be made in-place, Ed Chum's method based on `.loc` and sachinnm's method based on `reindex` cannot.

While other methods are generic, citynorman's solution is limited to `pos=0`. I didn't observe any performance difference between `df.loc[cols]` and `df[cols]`, which is why I didn't include some other suggestions.

Original system (2019): <strike>Python 3.6.8 and pandas 0.24.2 on a MacBook Pro (Mid 2015).</strike>
Current system (2022): Python 3.10.5 and pandas 1.4.3 on a MacBook Pro (2021, Apple M1).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_cols = 11
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(200000, n_cols),
                  columns=range(n_cols))

def move_column_inplace(df, col, pos):
    col = df.pop(col)
    df.insert(pos, col.name, col)

def move_to_front_normanius_inplace(df, col):
    move_column_inplace(df, col, 0)
    return df

def move_to_front_chum(df, col):
    cols = list(df)
    cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index(col)))
    return df.loc[:, cols]

def move_to_front_chum_inplace(df, col):
    col = df[col]
    df.drop(col.name, axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.insert(0, col.name, col)
    return df

def move_to_front_elpastor(df, col):
    cols = [col] + [ c for c in df.columns if c!=col ]
    return df[cols] # or df.loc[cols]

def move_to_front_sachinmm(df, col):
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index(col)))
    df = df.reindex(columns=cols, copy=False)
    return df

def move_to_front_citynorman_inplace(df, col):
    # This approach exploits that reset_index() moves the index
    # at the first position of the data frame.
    df.set_index(col, inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return df

def test(method, df):
    col = np.random.randint(0, n_cols)
    method(df, col)

col = np.random.randint(0, n_cols)
ret_mine = move_to_front_normanius_inplace(df.copy(), col)
ret_chum1 = move_to_front_chum(df.copy(), col)
ret_chum2 = move_to_front_chum_inplace(df.copy(), col)
ret_elpas = move_to_front_elpastor(df.copy(), col)
ret_sach = move_to_front_sachinmm(df.copy(), col)
ret_city = move_to_front_citynorman_inplace(df.copy(), col)

# Assert equivalence of solutions.
assert(ret_mine.equals(ret_chum1))
assert(ret_mine.equals(ret_chum2))
assert(ret_mine.equals(ret_elpas))
assert(ret_mine.equals(ret_sach))
assert(ret_mine.equals(ret_city))
```

**Results**:

```py
# For n_cols = 11:
%timeit test(move_to_front_normanius_inplace, df)
# 137 µs ± 692 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_citynorman_inplace, df)
# 177 µs ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_sachinmm, df)
# 821 µs ± 11.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_chum, df)
# 926 µs ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_elpastor, df)
# 901 µs ± 6.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_chum_inplace, df)
# 3.25 ms ± 32.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# For n_cols = 31:
%timeit test(move_to_front_normanius_inplace, df)
# 188 µs ± 3.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_citynorman_inplace, df)
# 214 µs ± 649 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_sachinmm, df)
# 5.17 ms ± 68.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_chum, df)
# 5.52 ms ± 82.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_elpastor, df)
# 5.48 ms ± 198 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit test(move_to_front_chum_inplace, df)
# 14.7 ms ± 317 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Above are the updated values for a rerun in 2022. The rankings have remained stable over the past years for different systems, although the absolute numbers have decreased by factors between 2 and 10, from which citynorman's solution and my solution (normanius) have benefited the most.

Comment: Great solution. However, we should not assign the modified df with the inserted column to the original df explicitly. So instead of `df = df.insert(0, col.name, col)`, we need to do `df.insert(0, col.name, col)`. You have it correctly in the function ```move_column_inplace()``` though.

Comment: Thanks @normanius.  Been working hard in Dexter's Laboratory I see. :-) Great solution.  Occam's Razor. Simple and elegant.

Comment: I also prefer this solution :)

Comment: What about test with multiple columns move? :)

Answer (score 53):

You can use the df.reindex() function in pandas.
df is

```
                      Net  Upper   Lower  Mid  Zsore
Answer option                                      
More than once a day  0%  0.22%  -0.12%    2     65
Once a day            0%  0.32%  -0.19%    3     45
Several times a week  2%  2.45%   1.10%    4     78
Once a week           1%  1.63%  -0.40%    6     65
```

define an list of column names

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols
Out[13]: ['Net', 'Upper', 'Lower', 'Mid', 'Zsore']
```

move the column name to wherever you want

```
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('Mid')))
cols
Out[16]: ['Mid', 'Net', 'Upper', 'Lower', 'Zsore']
```

then use `df.reindex()` function to reorder

```
df = df.reindex(columns= cols)
```

out put is: df

```
                      Mid  Upper   Lower Net  Zsore
Answer option                                      
More than once a day    2  0.22%  -0.12%  0%     65
Once a day              3  0.32%  -0.19%  0%     45
Several times a week    4  2.45%   1.10%  2%     78
Once a week             6  1.63%  -0.40%  1%     65
```

Answer (score 25):

I didn't like how I had to explicitly specify all the other column in the other solutions.

```
cfg_col_sel = ['Mid', 'Zscore']
cfg_col_sel = cfg_col_sel+[s for s in df.columns if not s in cfg_col_sel]
df = df[cfg_col_sel]
```

This is another way of doing it but less flexible

`df = df.set_index('Mid').reset_index()`

Comment: This exploits that current versions of `reset_index()` insert the dropped index at the first position. Note, however, that this behavior is not specified in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Comment: As for the performance, see my answer. It's advantageous to use `inplace=True` for both `set_index()` and `reset_index()`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a generic set of code that I frequently use to rearrange the position of columns. You may find it useful.

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
n = int(cols.index('Mid'))
cols = [cols[n]] + cols[:n] + cols[n+1:]
df = df[cols]
```

Comment: ideally, explain your answer and what makes it a good solution, and not only post a piece of code. You are risking downvoting

Answer (score 5):

To reorder the rows of a DataFrame just use a list as follows.

```
df = df[['Mid', 'Net', 'Upper', 'Lower', 'Zsore']]
```

This makes it very obvious what was done when reading the code later.  Also use:

```
df.columns
Out[1]: Index(['Net', 'Upper', 'Lower', 'Mid', 'Zsore'], dtype='object')
```

Then cut and paste to reorder.

---

For a DataFrame with many columns, store the list of columns in a variable and pop the desired column to the front of the list. Here is an example:

```
cols = [str(col_name) for col_name in range(1001)]
data = np.random.rand(10,1001)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

mv_col = cols.pop(cols.index('77'))
df = df[[mv_col] + cols]
```

Now `df.columns` has.

```
Index(['77', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
       ...
       '991', '992', '993', '994', '995', '996', '997', '998', '999', '1000'],
      dtype='object', length=1001)
```

Comment: What if you work with a DataFrame consisting of 1001 columns?

Comment: The concept is the same, however with many columns the columns should be stored in a list and the list should be manipulated.  See my edits above for an example.  My example is effectively the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/51009742/5827921.

Answer (score 3):

```py
df.set_index('Mid').reset_index()
```

seems to be a pretty easy way about this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **move a column to the front of the datafram**e, you can use
use [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

```
df.set_index(df.pop('column_name'), inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

---

You first need to set the column you want to bring to the front as the index of the dataframe (and we do a `pop` in order to drop the column from the original dataframe before setting it as the index in order to avoid name collision in the next action) and finally call `reset_index()` to make the old index the first column of the dataframe.

---

For more details see [How to change the order of dataframe columns in pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns-in-pandas-c91370326053).

Comment: This one resets your index, which may cause problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

#### Here is a very simple answer to this.

Don't forget the two (()) 'brackets' around columns names.Otherwise, it'll give you an error.

```
# here you can add below line and it should work 
df = df[list(('Mid','Upper', 'Lower', 'Net','Zsore'))]
df

                             Mid   Upper   Lower  Net  Zsore
Answer option                                                
More than once a day          2   0.22%  -0.12%   0%    65 
Once a day                    3   0.32%  -0.19%   0%    45
Several times a week          4   2.45%   1.10%   2%    78
Once a week                   6   1.63%  -0.40%   1%    65
```

Comment: clearly OP doesn't want to explicitly spell out the column names. In some cases with very wide dataframes it might not even be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use movecolumn package in Python to move columns:

```
pip install movecolumn
```

Then you can write your code as:

```
import movecolumn as mc
mc.MoveTo1(df,'mid')
```

Hope that helps.

P.S : The package can be found here. https://pypi.org/project/movecolumn/

Answer (score 1):

Easy and quick solution::

For pandas >= 1.3 (Edited in 2022):

```
df.insert(0, 'mean', df.pop('mean'))
```

How about (for Pandas < 1.3, the original answer)

```
df.insert(0, 'mean', df['mean'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simplist thing you can try is:

```
df=df[[ 'Mid',   'Upper',   'Lower', 'Net'  , 'Zsore']]
```