# How to modify pandas df in order to adjust starting point of plot for series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Im trying to plot a dataframe like this:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2, 8, 2], [2, 4, 4, 20, 2], [3, 3, 1, 20, 2], [4, 2, 2, 1, 0], 
              [5, 1, 4, -5, -4], [1, 5, 2, 2, -20], [2, 4, 4, 3, 0], [3, 3, 1, -1, -1], 
              [4, 2, 2, 0, 0], [5, 1, 4, 20, -2]],
             columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
             index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])


plt.plot(np.cumsum(A.transpose()))
```

It looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like the first print of the chart to start at 0 for all lines. I tried adding another column according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122099/move-column-by-name-to-front-of-table-in-pandas), but didn't work. For some reason the index didn't change and kept the newly created column at the end in the plot.

```
A['s'] = 0
cols = list(A)
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('s')))
A = A.loc[:, cols]
plt.plot(np.cumsum(A.transpose()))
```

[image]

Comment: You should of course share the code where you try to add the additional point(s), not the one that is working fine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest don't downvote immediately, give me a chance to improve the question.

Comment: I did not downvote and indeed I wrote this comment to give you the chance to improve the question, which you did, so everything is fine, I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is absolutely correct. The code from the question will produce the desired plot. However, only in matplotlib 2.2. In earlier versions matplotlib would automatically sort the categories alphabetically before plotting, such that row `s` is last in the axes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2, 8, 2], [2, 4, 4, 20, 2], [3, 3, 1, 20, 2], [4, 2, 2, 1, 0], 
              [5, 1, 4, -5, -4], [1, 5, 2, 2, -20], [2, 4, 4, 3, 0], [3, 3, 1, -1, -1], 
              [4, 2, 2, 0, 0], [5, 1, 4, 20, -2]],
             columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
             index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

A['s'] = 0
cols = list(A)
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('s')))
A = A.loc[:, cols]

plt.plot(np.cumsum(A.transpose()))

plt.show()
```

[image]

In case you cannot use matplotlib 2.2, you may plot the values without labels and set the labels afterwards.

```
x = np.arange(len(A.columns))
y = np.cumsum(A.transpose()).values
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x, A.columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) to add a new column with all 0's.

```
A.insert(0, '0', [0]*10)
```

- The first `0` ist the position of your column, in this case the
  beginning of your dataframe.
- `'0'` is the name of the column. As `.plot` sorts your columns, you
  either can use something that comes before your other columns (like
  probably `'0'`) or you have to reorder your columns in your plot.
- `[0]*10` are the values of your new column.

[image]

Comment: I wonder why naming the column `"0"` is a solution if it is supposed to be named `"s"`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I skipped this part of his question  unintentionally, to be honest. However, I am not sure if he really needs the column to be named 's' or if it is just a dummy name. There are a few possibilities for sorting the columns of a plot. You posted one of them. He can also set the order manually depending on his data. Nevertheless, you're right.